# Creating a home screen for my embedded board using Qt/Qt Quick

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am not an expert but I have been using Qt/QtEmbedded for sometime now, for SBC 6845. I have created a few applications and have successfully run them on my device.
 Now I want all of those applications to appear on a home screen. I understand that using QML/Qt Quick this might be achieved, but I don't have any idea on how to proceed with it. I have gone through some links and tutorials but most of them show how to create buttons and all that with Qt Quick, but not much than that. I am yet to find some tutorial/docs which can point me how to proceed with all applications on my home-screen. I need some directions, any links, advice on docs/books is welcome.

[While cross-compiling the QtEmbedded 4.6.2 libraries for my SBC I encountered problems with enabling opengl support. And, I am unaware of the other methods for using QtQuick2 without opengl.

The applications (5-6 of them) are QWidgets and linking icons require to stay in the home screen. I want to keep them as simple as possible without any effects for the icons.

Plainly speaking, I am trying to create a bunch of icons displayed on the home screen linked to those applications. The applications if launched in windows style application, (or like a popup QDialog) will also serve my purpose.] 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is lacking details... For QtQuick2, you need an OpenGL ES2 device (or using mesa/clang/llvm). Those apps you want to launch... do you need those to be kinda embedded in your home screen ? Or is it just some icons grid launcher ? Are those QtWidget apps ?

Comment: I have added some more info, but I am unable to understand the difference between 'embedded in home screen' and 'icons in grid launcher'. If by 'embedded' you mean permanently positioned icons in the home screen then, yes that will also be fine.

Comment: By embedded i was asking if your homescreen was just some shortcuts launcher (with your "applications" being separate applications, launched and forget by your homescreen-launcher). Or wether your "applications" were only widgets, embedded and displayed within the homescreen window (acting more like some graphical shell for you applications than a separate launcher). I assumed the latter in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- > "I have gone through some links and tutorials but most of them show
  >   how to create buttons and all that with Qt Quick, but not much than
  >   that"

  For this part of the question, I'd advise you to download QtCreator
  and start playing with the demos (using more than just some buttons:
  you have demos for ListViews, GridViews, Delegates, Animations,
  Particles, QtQuick Layouts (Qt5.1 only), QtQuick Controls (Qt5.1
  only).

  There's also the rather complete :
  http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/qt5-everywhere-demo
- I'm completely unfamiliar with all the embedded/cross-compiling
  aspects of your question.
- About OpenGL/QtQuick2 : http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30483
  http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17201

  Also note that you can embed QtQuick2 scenes into a QWidget, but not
  the other way around (no QtWidget inside the scenegraph).

---

So maybe the easiest/fastest way to go for you would be to stick with Qt4 or Qt5 declarative/QtQuick1 module (might be deprecated/removed starting with Qt 5.2). In this setup, there is no scenegraph/mandatory need for OpenGL. And you can embed QWidgets into your qml scene (no scenegraph: it uses the QGraphicsView backend) via QGraphicsProxyWidget.

You'd then have some GridView (you also could use some Grid with a Repeater) filled with models and delegates (= a delegate acts as a template item to be filled with the model).

Your delegates would have states/maybe Loader(s) (for on-demand loading) : icon state and when clicked, some maximized state containing a loader, loading your widget through QGraphicsProxyWidget.

You already have half of this presented in this example (a grid + 2 states : small icons grid and maximized view, you only need to implement the delegate/loading/model/QGraphicsProxyWidget things):
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Implementing_parent_change_animation_with_QML